# Transfer data between Views

Tags: ios

I have two Views. Root and profile. When I push profile with method and dictionary, everything works fine. But if I use poptoviewcontroller to root, dictionary is empty.
I tried come back with push... animated:NO, but its no ok...

My method in both views:

```
-(void)transferDictionary:(NSMutableDictionary *)dic
{
self.transferDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]     initWithDictionary:dic];
}
```

Could You help me please?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Sending data from Profile to Root?

Comment: Data from root to profile (dictionary) is ok - dictionary is with data. But when poptoviewcontroller from profile to root dictionary is null. Via push it works fine, but push instead pop is not a good solution..

Comment: I don't understand what your trying to do. Are you trying to assign data from Profile back to Root? One thing to note is that when a viewController is popped from the navigation stack it's also deallocated.

Comment: You're popping back to the root view without passing back the dictionary. You need to either pass the value back like you did going forward, or make the dictionary accessible to both classes

Comment: i used delegate and it works, thank you